# Django merge 2 querysets in staggered/alternating fashion?

Tags: python, django

In my Django app I have 2 querysets of the **same** object. I know I can merge 2 querysets using itertools and chain like so:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(first_queryset, second_queryset))
```

But this outputs a new queryset where the entire first one is followed by the entire second one like so:

```
[<first_queryset_1st_instance>, <first_queryset_2nd_instance>,       <first_queryset_3rd_instance>, <second_queryset_1st_instance>, <second_queryset_2nd_instance>, <second_queryset_3rd_instance>]
```

However, I really need an output that is alternating between each queryset instead of just appending the entire second queryset at the end of the first one like so:

```
[<first_queryset_1st_instance>, <second_queryset_1st_instance>,<first_queryset_2nd_instance>, <second_queryset_2nd_instance>, <first_queryset_3rd_instance>, <second_queryset_3rd_instance>]
```

What's the best way I can do this in python/django?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the result you need using [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) together.

Lets call the querysets `p` and `q`. Then you would do:

```
# Python 3.x
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
combined = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, chain(*zip_longest(p, q))))

# Python 2.7
from itertools import chain, ifilter, izip_longest
combined = list(ifilter(lambda x: x is not None, chain(*izip_longest(p, q))))
```

Let's explain how it works. First, `zip_longest` (`izip_longest` in Python 2) zips the querysets together. You want `zip_longest` instead of `zip`, so that the output continues after the shorter queryset has finished.

This creates an iterable like:

```
((p[0], q(0)), (p[1], q[1]), (p[2], q[2]), ..., (p[9], q[9]), (p[10], None))
```

Note this is an iterable of tuples, but you want a flat list. So next we use `chain`, using the `*` operator to unpack the result of `zip_longest`.

This creates an iterable like.

```
(p[0], q[0], p[1], q[1], ..., p[9], q[9], p[10], None)
```

That's almost what we want, but we've got `None`s at the end if one queryset is shorter than the other. We can get rid of them with `filter` (`ifilter` in Python 2).

Comment: if there is overlap between results in p and q, what do you recommend to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: @w-- that's not part of the original problem so it would be better to ask a new question.

Comment: cool thanks. I've created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834009/django-merge-2-querysets-in-staggered-alternating-fashion-without-duplicates