# Django merge 2 querysets in staggered/alternating fashion without duplicates?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, python-itertools

Follow up question to this one:
[Django merge 2 querysets in staggered/alternating fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512741/django-merge-2-querysets-in-staggered-alternating-fashion/32512919)

I'm wondering is there an efficient way to avoid duplicates in the result? i.e. the generators will only return items we have not seen before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300735/django-union-of-different-queryset-on-the-same-model check this

Comment: Look at `QuerySet.union` if you use Django 1.11